# How to define a class that can save variadic template arguments?

Tags: c++, class, variadic-templates, definition, c++17

```
template<typename... Args>
struct A
{
    Args&... args_;
    //
    // error : only function and template parameters can be parameter packs
    //

    A(Args&... args) : args_(args)
    {}
};

int main()
{
    auto a = A(1, 2, 3);
}
```

My compiler is `clang 5.0` with `-std=c++1z`.

**How to define a class that can save variadic template arguments in such a case?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's not possible as far as I know. You have to use a `std::tuple` to store the parameters:

```
template<typename... Args>
struct A
{
    std::tuple<std::decay_t<Args>...> args_;

    A(Args&&... args) : args_(std::make_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...))
    {}
};
```

As of C++17, you can use [`std::apply`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply) to cal functions with `args_` as parameters, instead of unpacking them:

```
std::apply(func, args_);
```

Comment: The `std::move` is irrelevant if the arguments are passed by value though. `Args&&... args`?

Comment: The use of `std::apply` to unpack such tuples back into a pack should probably be mentioned.